# Add escape character in front of specific characters [oracle sql]

Tags: sql, oracle

What I am looking for is some regexp that will add `\\` character in varchar column in front of certain characters (e.g `"`, `\` ... N chars).

example: `James"Bond\007` -> `James\"Bond\\\007`

I can do this with N replace but I am looking for more elegant solution if oracle provides it.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnX, '\', '\\'), '"', '\"')
```

P.S need for oracle 12.1 & oracle 12.2

Comment: Hint: (1) character classes (2) back references (in regular expressions)

Comment: Have you looked into [`REGEX_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)? Could be useful in your case.

Comment: @Lucas I have and It does not, it can replace all x|y|z chars to k, not to k[x|y|z]

Comment: Demonstrating character classes and back references. See this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04fc96846087db03813ba2e745973568)

Comment: ah now I get it @Abra , thanks for helping me understanding how to use back references :)

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need this? if it is for somewhere later on, then handle escaping *there* following the rules that apply there.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing for parsing json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use back-references:

```
select regexp_replace ( 
         'James"Bond\007',
         '("|\\)', -- add all the characters you want to replace
         '\\\1'
       )
from   dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('JAMES"BOND\007','("|\\)','\\\1')   
James\"Bond\\007
```

Note you need to escape the back-slashes in your regex with an extra backslash!